# Stacked Bar Chart --> Stacked Column Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to convert this regular bar chart into a stacked column chart. I have been playing around with JSfiddle for a while and just can't get it.

I'm assuming my issue is rather small but I just can't identify it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>


google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Method', 'Box Office', 'Call Center', 'Group Sales', 'Subscription',
         'Web', { role: 'annotation' } ],
['Day 0', 960, 146, 0, 0, 406, ''],
['Day 1', 690, 191, 25, 4, 457, ''],
['Day 2', 189, 191, 35, 4, 443, ''],
['Day 3', 185, 138, 14, 3, 443, ''],
['Day 4', 130, 135, 21, 3, 416, ''],
['Day 5', 181, 216, 22, 9, 659, ''],
  */

      ]);

      var options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: 500,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
        bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
        isStacked: 'percent'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of your chart.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data =google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Method', 'Box Office', 'Call Center', 'Group Sales', 'Subscription',
         'Web', { role: 'annotation' } ],
['Day 0', 960, 146, 0, 0, 406, ''],
['Day 1', 690, 191, 25, 4, 457, ''],
['Day 2', 189, 191, 35, 4, 443, ''],
['Day 3', 185, 138, 14, 3, 443, ''],
['Day 4', 130, 135, 21, 3, 416, ''],
['Day 5', 181, 216, 22, 9, 659, '']
      ]);
     var options = {
         width: 600,
        height: 400,
        isStacked: true,
        legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },

         seriesType: "bars",
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n53tqsnw/

You are making mistake at calling the chart with google.visualization.BarChart which should be google.visualization.**ComboChart**.

Hope this will help you.